# Bootstrap Admin-Dashboard Template - How to use it or apply it?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to design a site with Bootstrap and came across admin-dashboard templates. Since Bootstrap is not a CMS System, I did not understand the aim of it and where to apply these themes.

I need a real life example or an explanation.

Here are some templates: https://wrapbootstrap.com/themes/admin

Comment: I use this https://almsaeedstudio.com/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

These are just the themes that you use to create the CMS out of, they are made with boot strap which is CSS just the design.

You will need to program the CMS your self or read a tutorial on how to integrate them into your preferred CMS System (If you can change the admin theme ??).

I normally use 
http://usman.it/free-responsive-admin-template/ or -
http://medialoot.com/browse/search?channel=resources&category=&keywords=free+admin